# php sql, regex digit comma digit

Tags: php, sql, preg-match, dump

Ive got an sql dump and wanna loop through the rows then change, delete and insert specific field(s) in each row. Now I need to replace all occurrences of the sql `','` that starts and ends each fields value.

I only need help for my last problem. I need to replace all commas that have a digit number before and after the comma with my splitter `#***#`.

I found this regex, `/(^\d,\d)*$/` but some how it does not do the job! I have fields with text that include comma so I dont wanna replace those ofcause

```
$sqlrows = str_replace(",",'#***#',preg_match('/(^\d,\d)*$/', $sqlrows)); 
// defines sql dump regex [0-9],[0-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use preg_replace() rather than str_replace() something like this:

```
$sqlrows = preg_replace( '/(^\d,\d)*$/', "#***#", $sqlrows );
```

Answer (score 0):

> "I need to replace all commas that have a digit number before and after
>   the comma with my splitter #***#."

Try this approach:

```
<?php
$str = '1,2
3,4
';
$str = preg_replace('/(\d),(\d)/', '$1#***#$2', $str);

print $str;
```

prints:

```
1#***#2
3#***#4
```

I am finding all the commas, surrounded by digits, and replace them with your separator, keeping the digits intact by using backreferences.